# Is it possible to prevent rogue/unauthorised computers booting from your PXE server?

Tags: windows, windows-10

In the below scenario, is it possible to prevent a rogue/unauthorised laptop plugging into the network and installing our Windows image? 
What risks are we exposed to should a malicious 3rd party boot a laptop from PXE to acquire a domain joined machine.

Windows 10 Enterprise images are available via PXE 
Windows images are configured to automatically join the domain
Windows images are configured to use DirectAccess
Any computer plugged in with a network cable on site is able to PXE boot

I'm wondering if there's a way we could password protect the PXE server.

Comment: 1. MAC address restriction(it is still susceptible to MAC spoofing) 2. Boot image authentication policy : all bootup image should ask a password after boot up. Use second factor authentication if budget allow.